# iPhone app not reloading data after reopening

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am new to objective-c and iPhone app development. Currently I've been faced with a problem that I'm not sure how to fix. The problem is that I want my app to completely close and release all data when the user presses the home button and then when the user reopens the app it refreshes the data from my online server. I am currently testing on the iPhone simulator and it seems that when the user reopens the program it reopens the old state and does not call the `viewDidLoad` method to refresh the data nor it calls the `-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` when the user presses the home button.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's probably because it just got suspended (multitasking).

You can either disable multitasking in the plist file:

set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `NO/false` (unchecked)

This disables multitasking completely. Or you can implement the new app delegates that get called on resuming and reload your data there:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```